# How to insert Data into sqlite Database using a generic function

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, expo

The function I'm coding will be called from other javascript file and the fields and values will be passed to the function including the table name. But when I run the function it just gives error without this error message

```
    We have encounter an Error WebSQLTransaction { "_complete": false, "_error": null, "_running": true, "_runningTimeout": false, "_sqlQueue": Queue { "first": undefined, "last": undefined, "length": 0, }, "_websqlDatabase": WebSQLDatabase { "_currentTask": TransactionTask { "errorCallback": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false, "successCallback": [Function anonymous], "txnCallback": [Function anonymous], }, "_db": SQLiteDatabase { "_closed": false, "_name": "mydb.db", }, "_running": true, "_txnQueue": Queue { "first": Object { "item": TransactionTask { "errorCallback": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false, "successCallback": [Function anonymous], "txnCallback": [Function anonymous], }, "next": Object { "item": TransactionTask { "errorCallback": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false, "successCallback": [Function anonymous], "txnCallback": [Function anonymous], }, "next": Object { "item": TransactionTask { "errorCallback": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false, "successCallback": [Function anonymous], "txnCallback": [Function anonymous], }, }, }, }, "last": Object { "item": TransactionTask { "errorCallback": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false, "successCallback": [Function anonymous], "txnCallback": [Function anonymous], }, }, "length": 3, }, "version": "1.0", }, }
```

So am building this using javascript React native and am using the expo SDK. Expo ships in the SQLite module, Again what am doing is to build a function that can be called from anywhere in the code and it some data into the database.

```
   export const insert = (tbl, fields, values) =>{
    const query = "insert into ${tbl} (${fields}) values (${values});";
    console.log(query);
    //it looks fine to me
    db.transaction(trx => {
        let trxQuery = trx.executeSql(
           query
        ,[values],(data)=> console.log('we made it',data),(err)=>console.log('We have encounter an Error', err))
        console.log(trxQuery); // retruns undefined
    })
}
```

This is how I called the function

```
    const personObj = JSON.parse(personDetails);
        Object.keys(personObj).map(i => 
            insert('users','name, address, hash', [personObj[i].name, personObj[i].address, personObj[i].hash])
        )
```

I expect to get a console log of `we made it` and information concerning the data we inserted. Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

success and error callback have 2 parameters first one is transaction itself second one is error or resultset. You should edit your code like below and check the resultset object,

```
`export const insert = (tbl, fields, values) =>{
    const query = "insert into ${tbl} (${fields}) values (${values});";
    console.log(query);
    //it looks fine to me
    db.transaction(trx => {
        let trxQuery = trx.executeSql(
             query
            ,[values]
            ,(transact,resultset) => console.log('we made it',resultset)
            ,(transact,err) => console.log('We have encounter an Error', err)
       );
    })
}`
```